# Label Encoding for columns with sentences or long texts - keras

Tags: python, encoding, keras, scikit-learn

I have been searching how to encode multiple columns with long or short texts, but I couldn't really find any good solutions. Here is an example from my data-set:

```
IP         Country  Domain          Attack           Signature          Thread
0.0.0.0.0  US       somedomain.net  compromized site 8787tgd9347343dex  yes
1.1.1.1.1  US       otherdomain.net trojan           74384399rfg99737h1 yes
```

So far I have tried `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder` from `sklearn`, but they didn't work. Any feedback, help, or direction is much appreciated.

EDIT

---

I figured I would give more details about what I am trying to accomplish

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv("export.csv", sep=",")

labelencoder = LabelEncoder()

def encoder(x = len(df.columns)):
    for i in range(x):
        df.iloc[:, i] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df.iloc[:, i])

encoder()
```

Now, I have a data frame with the below:

[image: screenshotspider]

However, this doesn't look like the right way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DictVectorizer` from `sklearn.feature_extraction`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

data=pd.read_csv('export.csv',encoding = "utf-8", header=0)
vectorizer = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data[data.columns[0:]].to_dict("records"))

print(X)
```

For the following input:

```
          IP Country           Domain            Attack           Signature Thread
0  0.0.0.0.0      US   somedomain.net  compromized site   8787tgd9347343dex    yes
1  1.1.1.1.1      US  otherdomain.net            trojan  74384399rfg99737h1    yes
```

The output looks something like this:

```
[[0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]]
```

Assuming that all the columns are training features, if the last column 'Thread' is a label you should modify the code :

```
ln=(len(data.columns)-1)
vectorizer = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data[data.columns[0:ln]].to_dict("records"))
Y = data[data.columns[ln]]
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks @Jithin let me give a try. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Sure @Infinite_Loop, let me know

Comment: Hi @Jithin, thank you again for your answer. I ended up using keras Tokenizer function, but you gave me the right direction so I'll accept your reply as answer.